# Miner speed conversion

Tags: hashpower, mining-technical-details, mining-pool-shares

What is the exact ratio one would use to convert Miner speed from `Hashes per second` to `Shares per second`, assuming Difficulty 1 shares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approximate ratio which is usually used in calculations is 2^32 hashes per share. If you want the exact ratio, it's 2^48/(2^16-1).

Comment: It's maybe more generic to say "2^32 hashes per share*difficulty". Some places let you select higher-than-1 difficulty for shares, which proportionally affects the number of hashes required.

Answer (score 4):

[From the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_soon_might_I_expect_to_generate_a_block.3F):

> "The average time to find a block can be approximated by calculating:
>   time = difficulty * 2**32 / hashrate"

This applies also to shares, setting 1 as the difficulty.

At 1 MH/s, you can expect to find a share every 2^32 / 1000000 = ~4295s.

Inversely, you will find (1000000/2^32) = ~0.000233 shares per second per MH/s.